# Calculate the derivatve of the differentiable function $f ( x, y, z ) = 2x^2 + 7y^2 + 2z^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

Calculate the derivatve of the differentiable function $f ( x, y, z ) = 2x^2 + 7y^2 + 2z^2$   according to the direction in the direction of the vector $v_p$, as $v = (1, 2, 3) \in\mathbb{R}^3$,  $P= (3,2,1)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $v_p$ is the tangent vector.

Here is my question, I found it on my differential geometry book without a solution and I couldn't solve. Can you help? Thankss..

Comment: You have to find the directional derivative respect to the vector $v_p$ and evaluate it in the point $(3,2,1)$ right?

Comment: yes that is right

Answer (score 1):

First you have to calculate the gradient of your function:
$$f'_x=4x,f'_y=14y,f'_z=4z \implies\nabla f(x,y,z)=(4x,14y,4z).$$
If we now evaluate the gradient of $f$ in $(3,2,1)$ we find $\nabla f{(3,2,1)}=(12,28,4)$.
The vector $v=(1,2,3)$ is such that $||(1,2,3)||=\sqrt{14}$, so we have to normalize it in order to find a versor whose norm is $1$: $v'=\dfrac{(1,2,3)}{||(1,2,3)||}=\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{14}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}\Big)$. In conclusion:
$$D_{v'}f(3,2,1)=\Big\langle\nabla f(3,2,1),\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{14}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}\Big)\Big\rangle= \frac{12}{\sqrt{14}} +\frac{56}{\sqrt{14}}+\frac{12}{\sqrt{14}}=\frac{40\sqrt{14}}{7}$$